# How can I compare a "MM/DD/YYYY"  date with the Date() function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

How can I compare a date input of format "MM/DD/YYYY" with the `Date()` function in Javascript?

For example:

```
if (InputDate < TodaysDate){
  alert("You entered past date")
}
else if (InputDate > TodaysDate){
  alert("You entered future date")
}
else if (InputDate = TodaysDate){
  alert("You entered present date")
}
else{
  alert("please enter a date")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all! Didnt find any of the above to work, but got it to work finally. Had to hack a little ;)

I did it by splitting the Date using getMonth, getDate and getYear and Parsing it and then comparing it. It works just as I want:

```
Date.parse(document.getElementById("DateId").value) < Date.parse(dateToday.getMonth() + "/" + dateToday.getDate() + "/" + dateToday.getYear())
```

Answer (score 5):

Convert the String to a Date using `new Date(dateString)`.  Then normalize today's date to omit time information using `today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)`.  Then you can just compare the dates as you have above:

```
var date = new Date(dateInput);
if (isNaN(date)) {
    alert("please enter a date");
}
else {
    var today = new Date();
    today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    var dateTense = "present";
    if (date < today) {
        dateTense = "past";
    }
    else if (date > today) {
        dateTense = "future";
    }
    alert("You entered a " + dateTense + " date");
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/w2sJd/

Comment: This doesn't take into account the timezone...your fiddle gives me this for today's date:  Please enter a date: 2019-03-27  : Tue Mar 26 2019 is a past date.

Comment: @TheEmirOfGroofunkistan - Actually the bug in this code is that it _does_ take time zone into account, since [JavaScript interprets that format as UTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#Date_Time_String_Format).  If you are trying to see if a given month, day, and year are the same, and your input strings are not in a consistent format, step one will be to normalize your strings. If they are all in `YYYY-MM-DD`, the solution is simply to [change `setHours` to `setUTCHours`](http://jsfiddle.net/r3o0fbvd/).

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) docs.

You need one Date object with the entered date (using either the constructor or the `setMonth` etc. methods) and one with the current date (no arguments to the constructor). You can then use `getTime` to get UNIX timestamps on both objects and compare them.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://www.datejs.com/. It will help you with standard date manipulation

Comment: Datejs is overkill for simple date comparison, especially when the date is in a known format.  It's just not worth including *another* library.  It's struck me as more of a toy app - impressive at first, but when trying out some real world natural language representations of dates, it isn't quite robust enough.  Eg, "ten o'clock", "6 this evening", "two days from today".  It hasn't been updated since 2007, so there's not much hope of that robustness being added.

Comment: Well, I understand what you mean, but doing date stuff in JavaScript can take a lot of time if you want to do it right. I think using an external library is worth the extra costs, but I agree that it has to be a maintained and stable one. I personally have not done a great deal of work with datejs, so I can only assume you are right. Building these kind of things yourself is counter productive and all new code contains bugs, so I always try to reuse existing and tested stuff.

Answer (score -3):

```
function compareDate(inputDateString) {
  var inputDate, now;
  inputDate = new Date(inputDateString);
  now = new Date();
  if (inputDate < now) {
    console.log("You entered past date");
  }
  else if (inputDate > now) {
    console.log("You entered future date");
  }
  else if (inputDate === now) {
    console.log("You entered present date");
  }
  else {
    console.log("please enter a date");
  }
}
```

Comment: This won't work for today's date for two reasons.  First, you are comparing by reference instead of by value.  `inputDate` does not reference the same Date object as `now`, though their values may be equal.  Second, a Date created by parsing `MM/dd/yyyy` will have hours, minutes, seconds, and ms all equal to `0`, whereas `new Date()` will containing time information (except for 1 ms per day).